# Efficient way to compute MIPS expression

Tags: assembly, mips

I am writing a program for a embedded computer and have VERY little memory and processing power to work with.

**y** and **a** are doubles stored in floating-point registers, and **x** is an **array of doubles**. What is the most efficient way of writing this expression in MIPS?

```
 y = y + a * x[i];
```

Comment: Well, what do you have right now? Is there any reason why you believe a modern C compiler wouldn't generate efficient code?

Comment: unfortunately I don't have to option to use C :(

Comment: Why would that be? I've used C to write software for systems with 8kB RAM and CPUs capable of executing perhaps a million instruction/second. Even if you're not going to write all of your code in C you could still use a C compiler to generate assembly code that you could base your own assembly code on.

Comment: Do you have branch delay slots (e.g. simulators like spim/mars have these turned off by default, but real H/W generally has them)? What is the context? That is, can you show the loop this is in [as well as a bit more setup] as it will affect the code a bit.

Comment: If you're really memory constrained, consider storing an array of 32bit floats instead of 64bit doubles.  You can still use doubles in registers for temporaries.  If you can afford the space and memory bandwidth for doubles, though, then you don't have to spend as much time worrying about rounding errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not fluent in MIPS assembler, so I will not bother with actual MIPS instructions, I will use something like plain English halfway to z80/x86 TASM, hopefully you will get the idea.

And I will assume you want to add a whole array, not just this single line, because that changes everything about the task.

If you really want just to optimize this single line, there's little room for making it fancy. Just load x[i], multiply it by a, and add result to y.

If you are talking about some fixed size array (like size 4 in matrices), there may be some direct unrolled way to do it faster than the following thing from me.

If we are talking about *some* array, that's different (but you should have posted it like that), you can save many *(n-1)* multiplications by summing the x array first:

```
    load r1, x_array_pointer
    load r2, x_array_end_pointer
    load fpr0, zero_value
:loop_sum_x_array
    add fpr0,[r1]
    add r1,size_of_double
    cmp r1,r2
    jump_less loop_sum_x_array ; till whole array is summed
    mul fpr0, *a* ; now multiply sum{x} by "a"
    add fpr0, *y* ; and add initial "y" value
    ; fpr0 contains result
```

"Algorithm": y + a*x0 + a*x1 + a*x2 + ... **=** y + a*(x0 + x1 + x2 + ...) *(If you didn't figure this one on your own before you posted at SO, you either didn't even try, or you are 8y old, or you should seriously do some thinking and basic math exercises, because this is like obvious. Heh, actually, at this level of difficulty it's pure fun, why do you let others at SO live **yours** fun? You are very generous sir. :) )*

Memory: this doesn't use any additional memory, only the input **y**, **a** and **x**, you need few temporary registers (r1, r2, fpr0) (so as long as you are not doing 8bit CPU exercise, you should have enough of spare ones for this).

Processing power: complexity of algorithm is O(n) (and as you have to add each value from x array, you can't beat that). The inner loop is using quite basic instructions: one floating point addition, load of double-value from memory, address incrementing, compare and conditional jump. Then it needs literally **one** floating point multiply and one more fp addition. The x array is accessed in sequential way, so memory cache misses should be minimal.

If your CPU has any specialized instructions like MMX, the sum for large arrays can be written probably faster by utilizing those. But on modern CPU+RAM for large arrays you will be mostly limited by memory cache speed, as that inner loop is like non-existent for GHz CPU (except loading value from memory of course).

edit: as Michael noted, using C compiler is the right way, I did my answer just for fun of writing some pseudo-assembler. I'm not sure what your platform is, but if it's worth something, there must be cross compiler for PC plus way to get the binary result to the target.

Comment: This is a perfectly acceptable answer, do you mind some advises? 1) Be mature. Leave out the thing about *being 8yo* and *having fun*. It sounds like a teen talking about sex. 2) Respond to comments with comments (last paragraph). 3) Avoid walls of text, format 4) Things about the cache and SIMD instrs are a bit naive, modern CPUs must be kept busy (by avoiding bottlenecks) in every part not just load/stores. 5) Be accurate: 8 bit implies nothing about the number of registers, the array is accessed sequentially (not linearly), MMX is really old and specific, O(n) is a Theta(n), ...

Comment: 1) thanks :) 5) Last CPU known to me with limited amount of registers is 6502/6510 from 8bit era, anything 16bit had plenty (when compared to 6502). MIPS is RISC-like, so actually it has plenty^2. 4) what are you doing between the memory load/stores? (unless you program in some high level language) Back when I started with at Z80, the speed ratio register vs memory was around 1:2, it was reasonable to do some calculations even in memory. Modern PC gets about 1-2 instructions done per single clock tick! L0 4k page cache miss can be 1000+ ticks. You either do some calculations or wait for RAM.

Comment: 8 bit microcontrollers are still used a lot nowadays, on embedded systems that don't need performance but need to run reliably in a very long time. Most of them have only 1 register (accumulator) except AVR and a few I don't know